# How to get a StorageFolder from an user-friendly (localized) path?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

How to get a StorageFolder from a user-friendly (localized) path?

Folders can have a user-friendly (localized) name. The name can be read via:

```
StorageFolder.DisplayName
```

Example: The Folder 'C:\Users' is shown on a 'German' Windows as 'C:\Benutzer'.

I would like to get the StorageFolder from a user-friendly path like the Windows Explorer. However, calling the following method throws an exception:

```
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\Benutzer");
```

Is there some support in WinRT API to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure it is or isn't supported but I've never seen something like that. One workaround might be to build a table mapping know folders displays name to real names and then preprocess you path to eventually detect and replace display names.

Comment: @Tristan: Unfortunately, you have modified my question in a wrong way. I'm not using the WinRT API in a Windows Store application. I'm using it in a .NET WPF application that is not limited by the access of the file system.

Comment: Sorry about that, it pays dividends to be specific in your question and tags. Feel free to revert the edit if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I'm not explicitly answering the localised part of your question, but it's entirely possible that you're falling foul of a permissions issue that I describe below.

It's not possible in WinRT to access the file system** without it being user initiated.

The mechanism they have in WinRT for what you're describing is to ask the user to [pick the location via a folder picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), then to add that chosen folder to the FutureAccessList for programmatic access later.

```
StorageFile folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
folderToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);
//Keep this folder token to access the folder programmatically later
```

You can [access that folder](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2011/10/10/winrt-storage-accesscache/) later using the following.

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(folderID);
```

Note that there's absolutely no exception handling in this example. Check the links (particularly the latter) for more details.

** As in your example, however there are standard folder / file resources you can access without this.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the `StorageFolder` located into app install path - `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path` by specifying the path manually, for example you downloaded a folder with subfolders and you want to get a file from there, you'll use:

```
StorageFolder customAppFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + @"\yourFolder\yourSubfolder");
```

now you can iterate files in that subfolder:

```
 IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> filesInFolder =await appFolder.GetFilesAsync();

  foreach (StorageFile file in filesInFolder){
  Debug.WriteLine(file.Name);
 }
```